Doubt about Lemma 13.16 Yeh, Real Analysis
Lemma Let $f$ be an absolutely continuous real-valued function on $[a, b ]$. If $f' = 0$ a.e. on $[a, b]$ then $f$ is constant on $[a, b]$.
Proof To show that $f$ is constant on $[a, b]$ we show that for every $c\in (a, b]$ we have
$f(c) = f(a)$. Now since $f' = 0$ a.e. on $[a, b]$, we have $f' = 0$ a.e. on $(a, c)$. Thus there
exists a null set $F\in(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$ contained in $(a, c)$ such that $f' = 0$ on $E= (a, c)\setminus F$.
We have $E\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) $ with $\lambda(E)=\lambda((a,c))=c-a<\infty.$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $\eta>0$ be arbitrarily given. Let $\delta>0$ be a positive number corresponding to our $\varepsilon>0$ in the definition for the absolute continuity of $f$ on $[a,c]$. Now, at every $x\in E$ we have that $f'(x)=0$ so that there exists $h_x>0$ such that $$\lvert f(x+h)-f(x)<\eta h\quad\text{for every}\quad h\in (0,h_x).$$ Then the collection of closed intervals $$\mathcal{B}=\{[x, x+h]\; :\; h\in (0, h_x), x\in E\}$$ is a Vitali cover of $E$. Since $\mu(E)<\infty$ by the Vitali Covering Theorem there exists a finite disjoint subcollection $\{I_k\; |\: k=1,\dots, N\}$ of $\mathcal{B}$ such that $$\lambda\left( E\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^N I_k\right)<\delta\tag1.$$ For each $x\in E$ let $h_x>0$ be chosen so small that $x+h_x<c$. Let $I_k=[x_k, y_k]$ with $x_k\in E\subset (a,b)$ for $k=1,\dots, N$ and let $\{I_k\;|\; k=1,\dots, N\}$ be so numbered that $$y_0:=a<x_1<y_1<x_2<y_2<\cdots < x_N<y_N<c:=x_{N+1}.$$ Since $E\subset (a,c)$ and $\lambda(E)=\lambda((a,b))$, $(1)$ implies that $$\lambda\left((a,c)\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^N I_k\right)<\delta\tag2$$

Question. How can I get $(2)$?

From $(1)$ it is possible to obtain that $$\lambda((a,c))=\lambda(E)<\delta+\lambda\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^N I_k\right)$$
But I can't understand why the fact that $E\subset (a,b)$ can help us. Can anyone give me some hits?

Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is an explanation of why you shouldn't.

Given that $E\subset (a,c)$ we have $(a,c)=E\,\cup [(a,c)\setminus E]$ and so $$\mu_L((a,c))=\mu_L(E)+\mu_L((a,c)\setminus E)$$
As $\mu_L((a,c))=\mu_L(E)$ we find $\mu_L((a,c)\setminus E)=0$.
Thus, we will have $$\begin{align}\mu_L\left((a,c)\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^NI_k\right)&=\mu_L\left(E\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^NI_k\right)+\mu_L\left([(a,c)\setminus E]\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^NI_k\right)=\\&=\mu_L\left(E\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^NI_k\right)+0<\delta\end{align}$$
where the second equality follows because $\left([(a,c)\setminus E]\setminus\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^NI_k\right)\subset (a,c)\setminus E$.
